# Angular HttpInterceptor not working with forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I have Service to get the token from type Observable and HttpInterceptor to use it to inject the token in every http request.
The thing is it works fine with a single request but if i used forkJoin i will not get any response back.

the interceptor code

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private service: AppService
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.service.token$.pipe(
      map((token: string) => {
        if (token) {
          const headers = req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
          console.log(`Request for url ${req.url}`);
          req = req.clone({
            headers: headers
          });
        }
        return req;
      }
      ),
      switchMap(newReq => next.handle(newReq))
    )
  }
}
```

and simple two requests like those

```
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
  }
```

And in the component

```
// Single One will work
 this.appService.getPosts().subscribe(res => console.warn(res));

// Will not work
    forkJoin([this.appService.getPosts(), this.appService.getUsers()])
      .subscribe(([posts, users]) => {
        console.log(posts, users);
      });
```

I re-produced the error on example you can check it 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpxvej

It will work only if i add take(1) in the interceptor but then it will not be the thing i want because i got a new value for the token will not use it.

and in other case if token was just a string will work 
like that

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.service.getToken();
    const headers = req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    console.log(`Request for url ${req.url}`);
    req = req.clone({
      headers: headers
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, in the interceptor if you make use of token as Observable and switchMap, you may end up one request cancel the other.

Your specific example would turn into: (getUsers fires -> intercepts adds token & getPosts fires -> intercept adds token) -> switchMap (cancel the previous intercepted request) -> only 1 request actually fires.

forkJoin requires both observables to be completed in order to fire, so your situation is one gets server response, the other remains silent.

You can use mergeMap instead of switchMap (which won't cancel the request), however the best solution would be using switchMap prior to calling the services function.

Also, it would be reasonable to make token as a string rather than observable as it rarely changes during a session, and you can make use of set-get to localStorage to make sure it's up-to-date.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a bit late but in addition to Ngoc Nam Nguyen anwser (which was pretty helpful).
For me it helped switching to mergeMap inside of the inceptor and using take one to make sure any token changes wont affect the interceptor later.
So I ended up with an interceptor like that:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
return this.authFacade.token$.pipe(
  take(1),
  mergeMap((token: string) => {
    if (token && req.method === 'POST') {
      const request = req.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      });
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  })
);
}
```

So I was able to keep the token as an observable which I think is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following **Observable** configuration by adding the `forkjoin` as `observable`.

**service.ts**

```
getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {

        return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .map(res => { 
            return res;
          });
    }

getPosts(): Observable<any[]> {            
            return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
            .map(res => { 
                return res;
              });
        }

getForkJoin(): Observable<any>{
        return forkJoin(
            this.getUsers(),
            this.getPosts()           
        );
    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
this.appService.getForkJoin().subscribe(([users,posts]) =>{

console.log(users);
console.log(posts);

} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as i mentioned this example will work but if i used forkJoin for 2 observables for example will not work

Comment: Ready Do the following implementation and It will works

Comment: Thank you, but in angular 6 there is no res.json in new HttpClient, also i think the problem is somewhere in the interceptor because if i used token as string not Observable<string> will work in both single Observable and forkJoin

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by converting the token from Observable to be just a string. and i solved the problem by doing that.