# Angular HttpInterceptor not firing on nested Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-http-interceptors

I have a HttpInterceptor to add my Bearer token to all the calls to my WebApi.
This interceptor works perfectly on all my simple service calls.

But I have one place where I need to call 2 methods and use both results to build a combined model. I've already used MergeMap, ForkJoin and FlatMap to nest the observables but none of these seem to trigger my HttpInterceptor...

**This is the interceptor**

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

**The service calls**

```
public getPriceList(): Observable<CuttingGapPartPrice[]> {
    const list = sessionStorage.getItem(this.listSessionKey);
    if (list) {
        return of(JSON.parse(list) as CuttingGapPartPrice[]);
    }

    return super.getClient()
        .get(`/api/cutting-gap-part-prices`, { headers: super.getHeaders() })
        .pipe(map(response => {
            sessionStorage.setItem(this.listSessionKey, JSON.stringify(response));
            return response ? response as CuttingGapPartPrice[] : new Array<CuttingGapPartPrice>();
        }));
}

public getPowerList(): Observable<MotorPower[]> {
    const list = sessionStorage.getItem(this.listSessionKey);
    if (list) {
        return of(JSON.parse(list) as MotorPower[]);
    }

    return super.getClient()
        .get(`/api/motor-power`, { headers: super.getHeaders() })
        .pipe(map(response => {
            sessionStorage.setItem(this.listSessionKey, JSON.stringify(response));
            return response ? response as MotorPower[] : new Array<MotorPower>();
        }));
}
```

Individually they work perfect. But combined/nested they do not.

**Nested Call using MergeMap**

```
public getQuotationPrices(quotation: Quotation): Observable<QuotationPrices> {
    return this.cuttingGapPartPriceService.getPriceList().pipe(mergeMap(prices => {
        return this.motorPowerService.getPowerList().pipe(map(powers => {
            var result = new QuotationPrices();
            //Some custom logic

            return result;
        }));
    }));
}
```

I know that my problem is comparable to what is described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614121/angular-httpinterceptor-not-working-with-forkjoin), but I just don't understand how I can fix it.

**Edit - Nested Call using ForkJoin**

```
public getQuotationPrices(quotation: Quotation): Observable<QuotationPrices> {
    return forkJoin([this.cuttingGapPartPriceService.getPriceList(), this.motorPowerService.getPowerList()]).pipe(map(data => {
        const prices = data[0];
        const powers = data[1];
        var result = new QuotationPrices();


        return result;
    }));
}
```

**Results in network tab of chrome**
[image: Results in network tab of chrome]

Comment: I don't really see how the second snippet is related to the third one. My guess is that you never subscribe to the returned observable. Or that all your data is already in session storage, and thus no request is ever sent. If you do, then post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a stackblitz.

Comment: @JBNizet
I renamed the getList methods to make it more clear for you guys but I forgot to rename them in the Nested call (Fixed it now). The getQuotationPrices is being subscribed to and there is no data in the session storage. I can see the call being made in the network tab of the chrome developer tools. The call returns a 401 because it is missing the Bearer token in the Headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what the problem was.
It had nothing to do with the observables.
I provided the interceptors in the AppModule but these were overriden again by my SharedModule because I imported the HTTPClientModule of angular again.
The problem was fixed after removing the duplicate import.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be necessary. My guess is rather that you imported HttpClientModule in your lazy module.

Comment: I added this provider part in my AppModule.
 { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },

Comment: found the real cause (changed my answer)

Comment: Good to hear. It's just what I told you then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to **flatten the nested observables.** It may be that your inner observables are not getting subscribed **(Observables does not run unless they are subscribed)**. You can check [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tb1m4t) to see how nested observables are not running unless you subscribed to innerObservables or flatten them. Also as suggested by @JB Nizet, it would be really great if you can create a repo on stackblitz

Comment: I already used flatMap and it didn't solve anything. I do subscribe to the observable returned by getQuotationPrices. I can see the call being made to the first observable (getPriceList) in the network tab of the chrome developer tools. The call returns a 401 because it is missing the Bearer token in the Headers.